# JWPlayer plays videos at 3x speed on the first run, then works fine in subsequent runs on the same pageload

Tags: flash, video-streaming, jwplayer

Go here: http://nano.materials.drexel.edu/research/videolibrary

For some bizarre reason, the videos will play at 3x speed on the first run through, but then will play at normal speed each subsequent play.  This doesn't happen all the time, and it's not always the same video(s) that do it.  I'm utterly baffled. I've reconverted the videos from m4p to flv (using BitComet's converter) several times, double checking the settings each time through with no change to the behavior.

Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It must be something transient or local to your network configuration - I just watched all the videos, twice, and they played normally in every case.

What is the configuration of the machine you're watching on? Does the problem occur on other machines, or just yours? Do you have any kind of caching software or other proxying infrastructure between you and the videoserver?

Comment: Well that's interesting.  Everyone I had test the videos is on the same local network as the server.  Thanks for testing, I'll see if I can get to an outside network to try.

Comment: As for my configuration, I see this problem on Firefox and IE8 on Windows 7.  I don't remember if I see it when booted into Linux, however.